# C++ WCHAR: Cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, syntax

I'm trying to create a WCHAR:

```
LONG bufferSize = foo.bar() + 1;
WCHAR wszBaz[bufferSize];
```

The compiler issues an error:

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
error C2133: 'wszBaz' unknown size
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: I added `const` but it still gives the same error:

```
const LONG bufferSize = foo.bar() + 1;
WCHAR wszBaz[bufferSize];
```

Comment: A `const` variable with a value determined at runtime isn't a constant expression.

Comment: Why not use a wchar_t array or maybe even a wstring instead of a WCHAR array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array sizes must be constant expression:

```
const int foo = 10;
WCHAR array1[123]; // ok - 123 is a constant expression
WCHAR array2[foo + 10]; // ok too - the expression is constant
WCHAR array3[bar(123)]; // not ok - it may evaluate to the same thing every time, but function calls aren't seen as constant.
```

Note that `const` does not make something a const expression. A const expression is something that is constant at compile time. The compiler is smart enough to figure out that something like `5+5` is a const expression, but isn't smart enough to figure out that `foo(5,5)` is a const expression -- even if `foo(x,y)` just returns `x+y`.

In the next C++ standard (C++0x), you will be able to define functions as const-expressions.

Comment: Right, and I marked it as `CONST long`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Rosarch: That just means the variable is not mutable, not that it's a constant expression. It needs to be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 3):

The size of an array is a constant expression. `bufferSize` is not a constant expression.

Use a `vector`: `std::vector<WCHAR> wszBaz(bufferSize);`, or a `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a variable sized array on the stack.

The best way to do this is to create the array on the heap as follows:

```
WCHAR* pszBaz = new WCHAR[bufferSize];
```

You then need to remember to delete[] it when you have finished with it.

Even easier though is just to use [std::wstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55(VS.80).aspx) ...

Comment: It's totally illegal to create a variable sized array on the stack? Is that because someone could potentially create an array larger than the stack frame?

Comment: I'd say the best way to do any array allocation from the heap is a `vector`. :) @Rosarch: Yes, it's totally illegal. And yes, that's a potential issue. C99 supports variable-length arrays (VLA's), C++ does not.

Comment: @GMan ... arguably I'd suggest that std::wstring is a far simpler way than using a vector.  Use the right container and all that ;)

Comment: A `vector` gives you a legal interface to write to the contained elements as a contiguous array which more closely matches the original code. To answer whether a `std::basic_string` has a sufficient interface for the asker would need more context.

Comment: @Rosarch:  There's not a fundamental reason why it's illegal, but it was illegal in C90 and stays illegal in C++.  C99 has at least something similar, but in C++, you'd be expected to use a vector rather than a variable-length array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `std::wstring`?

If you need to make sure it has a certain number of bytes, you can either do that when you construct it:

```
std::wstring baz(bufferSize, ' ');
```

or you can use the reserve method:

```
std::wstring baz;
baz.reserver(bufferSize);
```